# Estou com uma duvida em relação ao ImageView

Tags: android, imagem

Estou com uma duvida em relação a ImageView tem como eu deixar uma imagem tremendo ou piscando assim que eu carregar a tela que ela esta? Alguem poderia me informar como postal algum tutorial

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. Mostre algum código se possível.

Comment: essa a questão não tenho nada, apenas gostaria de quando abrir a tela da imagem ela ficar se movimenta um pouco, estou pesquisando para ver se encontro algo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma animação para fazer isso.

Alguns links úteis:

- [Documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)
- [Pacote com as classe que tratam de animação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html)
- [Tutorial do site oficial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)
- [Outro Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, testa isso aqui (http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/imageview-animation-in-android.html), é um exemplo bem simples mas você pode tirar proveito. Abraço